# Books in Combinatorial optimization

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

I wrote  Combinatorial optimization in the title , but I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. Recently, I was getting more interested in Koing's theorem, Hall marriage theorem .  I am interested to see similar theorems (I know similar is subjective). I guess what I am looking for is combinatorial optimization.

I am wouldn't be interested about the algorithmic side of Combinatorial optimization. I just want to get exposed to some nice theorems of the subject like the ones I mentioned at the beginning. I need suggestions for a suitable book.

Note: I only took an undergrad course in graph theory. I don't mind if the book is a graduate level book as long as it does not assume a pre knowledge of the subject.

Thank you

**Edit:** I would also be interested about coloring problems of graphs and the chromatic number. I think I am interested  in problems where one is looking for a maximum or a minimum. But I am not interested in making algorithms to achieve a maximum or a minimum.

Comment: Lex Schrijver has both a 3-volume book on combinatorial optimization and a set of lecture notes ( http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/dict.pdf ). I don't think you can easily split away the algorithmic side from the slick side: the algorithms are as central to this subject as are proofs, and often *are* more or less the proofs. (What you can ignore, if you want to, is the running time estimates; but they aren't usually the hard part...) You'll probably like matroids if you want to see things similar to Hall and König.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Is what I am looking Combinatorial optimization or graph theory ?

Comment: Only you know best. I believe combinatorial optimization is the natural way to go from Hall and König. Extremal graph theory mostly restricts itself to graphs, about which it asks deeper questions.

Comment: @darijgrinberg  Thanks for your help. To give a better idea about what I am looking for I state this: I would also be interested about coloring problems of graphs and the chromatic number. I think I am interested in problems where one is looking for a maximum or a minimum. But I am not interested in making algorithms to achieve a maximum or a minimum.

Comment: @Amr I would recommend taking a look at Diestel's *Graph Theory*, and the author has put an edition [on-line for free](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/index.html).  There is no emphasis on algorithms and no prerequisites besides some set theory and the Jordan curve theorem (for planar graphs), and the emphasis is all on proofs.  Chapter 5 is devoted to graph coloring, but it sounds like you would also be interested in chapters 2 and 3.

Comment: @darijgrinberg After looking at all suggestions, I think your suggestion is the best. I'd like you to put it as an answer if you have time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Comments turned into an answer:]

I believe combinatorial optimization is the natural way to go from Hall and König. Extremal graph theory mostly restricts itself to graphs (rather than decorated graphs, matroids, jump systems and all the other fancy objects combinatorial optimization is occupied with), about which it asks deeper questions. It is you who will ultimately have to decide what is more natural *for you*.

Lex Schrijver has both a 3-volume book on combinatorial optimization and a set of lecture notes ( http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/dict.pdf ; these contain some extremal graph theory, too, in their Chapter 7). I don't think you can easily split away the algorithmic side from the slick side: the algorithms are as central to this subject as are proofs, and often are more or less the proofs. (What you can ignore, if you want to, is the running time estimates; but they aren't usually the hard part...) You'll probably like matroids if you want to see things similar to Hall and König.

Answer (score 2):

Applied Combinatorics. Alan Tucker.
It has some graph theory with the most prominent theorems and proofs, but also other techniques.
Link to 6th ed: http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP001993.html