# Let $G$ be bipartite, what is $\min\{|X_0|:\,X_0\subseteq X\,,N(X_0)=Y\}$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph. Let $X,Y$ be the two partite sets of $G$. Suppose further that $N(X)=Y$. Consider the problem of finding:
$$\min\{|X_0|:\,X_0\subseteq X\,,N(X_0)=Y\}$$

What are some nice theorems related to this problem? What are good algorithms to find this minimum?

Basically, where can I read more about this problem? Any papers that discuss this problem?

Thank you

**Edit:** I would also be very interested to know any upper bounds on the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $N(X)$ means the neighbors of $X$, i.e. the vertices of $Y$ that share an edge with some vertex of $X$. Your problem is called the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), and there is *a lot* of literature on the topic, for example it was one of the Karp's 21 NP-complete problems. Unfortunately, I cannot recommend anything specific.

To be more precise, you can formulate your problem as:

> Let the universe be $U = Y$ and set sets $S_v = N(\{v\})$, all collected in family $\mathcal{S} = \{ S_v \mid v \in V\}$, where $\bigcup \mathcal{S} = U$. What is the smallest (with respect to cardinality) cover of $U$ by sets of family $\mathcal{S}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you. I already noticed that the question is equivalent to the question that you put at the end of your answer. By the way, are there any upper bounds on the minimum ?

Comment: Hi. I t would be great if you can have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462836/books-in-combinatorial-optimization

Comment: @Amr What do you mean by upper bounds? Surely you cannot take more than $|\mathcal{S}|$ sets, but in the worst case you can have $S_i = \{i\}$, and then you need them all to cover whole $U$. As for the second question, I rely mainly on papers, so it would be hard for me to recommend any book on similar topics.

Comment: @dtlarek I meant good upper bounds. For example: Suppose that it were shown that $\frac{|X|}{\delta (G)}$ is an upper bound on the minimum if $G$ satisfies certain conditions. In this case, I would be interested to know about this theorem.

Comment: Said differently: I meant non-trivial bounds not trivial bounds

Comment: @Amr I would love to help, but I don't work with set cover that deep to know any interesting bounds. I would recommend finding some survey (possibly recent), or asking a question directly to a person who wrote some articles in that area (possibly recently). For example, find some papers, get authors names, find their emails (it's customary to add some contact data, also the personal or departmental web pages might also be helpful) and ask directly with a detailed description of what you would like to know. If you won't find an answer, you _will_ find how to find it. Good luck!

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help.